# Hide Input Type Submit Text In Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, css

I'm preparing a form [here](http://tinkerbin.com/NDG2MgtJ).

I've problem with the submit button in Internet Explorer 8. 
The button show 'Submit Query' text [on top of the image button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnXSu.jpg).

How to hide this text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried making the value blank like so `<center><input type="submit" class="subscribe-sidebar-submit" value=""/></center>`

additionally if you add `text-indent: -9000px; text-transform: capitalize;` to your button css it will remove the submit query and work in ie7 & ie8